# Appending the first Google search result to a df

Tags: python, list, google-search

I am trying to write a script that will run through a list of company names and locations, and search for their sustainability reports. I am new to coding and I am just stuck with the loop. In the data there are 2 columns `["company_name", "company_country"]`.

I need to create a loop that searches Google for `"company_name" + "company_country" + "sustainability report" OR "Net zero"` and appends the link of the first result to a new df. The code I have began with so far is as follows:

```
from googlesearch import search 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ACgr.csv', index_col=0) 


list_of_queries = ["sustainability report", "Net zero"]
results = []

for query in list_of_queries:
    results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=1, stop=1, pause=2))

print(results)
```

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.  You should find a different way to implement this such as crawling the websites yourself.

Comment: Oh okay! I had no idea, thanks for that!